# C vs C++: How to fix? Typedef Enum

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, typedef

I have found that code that works (although with warning) in C is now giving me an error when moved to C++. I'd like to know why this produces an error, and how to resolve.

I am converting someone elses code to C++ and this gave me the error (pulled out and tested in its own file)...

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum SPI_SSADDR_TYPE
{
    SSADDR0 = 0,
    SSADDR1 = 1,
    SSADDR2,
    SSADDR3,
    SSADDR4,
    SSADDR5,
    SSADDR6,
    SSADDR7,
    SSADDR8
} SPI_SSADDR;

void SPI_set_slave_addr( SPI_SSADDR slaveSelectAddr );

int main()
{
    SPI_set_slave_addr(SSADDR8);
    return 0;
}    

void SPI_set_slave_addr( SPI_SSADDR slaveSelectAddr )
{
    slaveSelectAddr = slaveSelectAddr & (SPI_SSADDR)(0x07); // This line
    printf("Test: %d\r\n", slaveSelectAddr);
    return; 
}
```

The error it produces is:

```
TypeDef.cpp: In function ‘void SPI_set_slave_addr(SPI_SSADDR)’:
TypeDef.cpp:26: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘SPI_SSADDR’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
slaveSelectAddr = (SPI_SSADDR)((int)slaveSelectAddr & 0x07);
```

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks... I should  have known. I'll mark it once Stackoverflow allows me to.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, unlike in C, you can't implicitly convert an integer type into an enumeration type. The result of the expression is an integer type, since enumerations are converted to integers when you perform arithmetic on them, and so must be explicitly converted back:

```
slaveSelectAddr = static_cast<SPI_SSADDR>(slaveSelectAddr & 0x07);
```

Comment: The usual solution, if he needs this a lot, would be to define overloaded operators to do it.

Comment: I'm seeing the upvotes here and wondering why this seems to be the better answer? The accepted and the voted ones does the same thing, does it not? As for the overload comment, I don't believe I need it a lot... yet I haven't ported the entire code, so if it comes down to it, I will overload it, just wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: @Demortes: Votes are the emergent behaviour of many independent minds; they only make sense on average. Perhaps some liked the longer explanation, or the C++ cast, or the lack of redundant castage; but the accepted answer is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the cast:

```
slaveSelectAddr = (SPI_SSADDR)(slaveSelectAddr & 0x07);
```

You can also use a more C++ version of the cast:

```
slaveSelectAddr = static_cast<SPI_SSADDR>(slaveSelectAddr & 0x07);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
slaveSelectAddr = static_cast<SPI_SSADDR>(static_cast<int>(slaveSelectAddr) & 0x07);
```